# MVC 5 - Bootstrap Textbox width not 100%

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

New to bootstrap and wanted to know I took this code off bootry and the textbox still is only 1/4 of the width, I want it to fill the width, Please help

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Large Input using Bootstrap 3</h1>
<p>How to make a large input field in Bootstrap 3</p>
<form role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="code">Name</label>
            <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-md-12">Submit1</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

What am I missing or is it a IE 11 flaw or mvc flaw. Please help

Even Firefox not displaying it correct

Comment: What do you mean by MVC? By the way your approach is wrong, if you read bootstrap docs, it's quite clear that you must have a column inside row, without any other class and with its own element. Something along `.container > .row > .col-something` and **then** insert something (inside the column element)

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else